# Is it possible to reference a package from not within an import statement?

Tags: scala

I'm writing a documentation about a Scala library. When I reference a certain package I do this with a String, e.g. `"com.my.example"` but would rather prefer to do this in a manner that gives me compile errors if anything breaks (e.g. `(com.my.example).mkString`).

Of course my IDE will warn me about such situations when refactoring and propose to fix those Strings for me. I'd just prefer to rely on the compiler instead of the IDE. Is this in some way possible? (Creating pseudo classes in each package to reference is not an option).

Answer (score 1):

The compiler doesn't include comments, so it wouldn't break on that.  You need to use scaladoc instead of scalac.
When you generate the documentation, you will see warnings for broken references.
For example I misspelled immutable intentionally and got this warning:

```
[warn] C:\...\Foo.scala:4: Could not find any member to link for "scala.collection.ommutable".
```

The key thing is to surround your references in double brackets [[ ]], eg:

```
/**
 * This is my link [[scala.collection.ommutable]]
 */
```

For more info, check out http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/scaladoc.html